# Not able to resolve "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send" in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I sometimes see this error on my page "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send" and I am not really sure what the problem is because it's a on and off issue. I am able to see the data in the browser just fine. There are times were I don't see this error and then there are times I do.

Here is the code snippet where I believe the error is coming from.

```
@using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;
@{ 
    string myLayout = ViewData["myLayout"].ToString();
   IEnumerable<ICMSElement> myCollection = Model.Elements("GalleryImage");
   bool containGallery = myCollection != null && myCollection.Count() > 0 && !myCollection.FirstOrDefault().Value.IsNullOrEmpty();   
   

    JArray myFeatureJSON = null;
    IEnumerable<JToken> featureSet = null;

    if (Cache["myFeatures"] == null)
    {

        WebClient getmyFeatures = new WebClient();

        try
        {
            string myFeatures = getmyFeatures.DownloadString(new Uri("https://data........."));
            myFeatureJSON = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(myFeatures) as JArray;
            Cache.Insert("myFeatures", myFeatureJSON, null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10));
        }
        catch (Exception featureError)
        {
            Response.Write(featureError.Message);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        myFeatureJSON = (JArray)Cache["myFeatures"];
    }    
}
```

Comment: Using WebClient is not recommended anymore, try to use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0). Both WebClient and HttpClient are using the machine infrastructure which your code is executing in. My guess is something environmental is changing in your machine, network level, or end-point server. For example running a VPN on the machine or having an unreliable network connection.

Comment: @MasoudKeshavarz so are you basically suggesting to replace the above line with this new code: HttpClient getmyFeatures = new HttpClient();  ?